# NodeJS Promise and Async Problems (Firebase)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

The problem is with the promises and the async function. "All moved" is supposed to be logged after everything in async.each is done. But nothing is ever logged.

Here is my exports functions:

```
var courier_id = data.ref.parent.key;
return admin.database().ref("firewall_queue/"+courier_id+"/orders").once('value',function(orders){
    //console.log(Object.keys(orders.val()));
    async.each(Object.keys(orders.val()), function (order, callback) {
        if(order != "none") {
            return moveToWaitingFromFirewall(order).then(callback())

        }
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log("All moved");
        return admin.database().ref("/firewall_queue/"+courier_id+"/orders/").remove().then(()=>{
            return pushToPending(courier_id,data.ref.key);
        })
    });
})
```

Here is my moveToWaitingFromFirewall function:

```
function moveToWaitingFromFirewall(order_id){
var order = {};
order.id = order_id;
var promises = [];
promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
    admin.database().ref("orders/"+order_id+"/zone").once('value').then(function(zone){
        order.zone = zone.val();
        resolve();
    })

}))
promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
    admin.database().ref("orders/"+order_id+"/time_order_placed").once('value').then(function(time_order_placed){
        order.time = time_order_placed.val();
        resolve();
    })
}))
//grab zone and time first
return Promise.all(promises).then(()=>{
    return admin.database().ref(order.zone+"/wait_order_queue/"+order.id).set(order.time);
})

}
```

JSON Firebase

```
"c98" : {
    "orders" : {
      "0333" : 123123,
      "0345" : 12,
      "0911" : 123,
      "none" : "none"
    }
```

Comment: Please structure and format you question better. And be clear what you want to achieve, what doesn't work as expected, and how you expect it to be!

Comment: @KevinVugts made the problem clear! Thank you

Comment: `.then(callback())` This looks wrong to me. Try `.then(callback)` or `then(()=>callback())`?

Comment: @CodyG I tried then(()=>callback()) and it also didnt work, ill retry since I made some minor changes just now. How do the promises look?

Comment: `return moveToWaitingFromFirewall(order).then(callback)` <- remove the `return` as well...

Comment: @CodyG no luck!

Comment: I think your promises need some cleanup, there might be a lot of unnecessary new promise generation, but I don't know if the functions you're calling are promises or not.

Comment: @CodyG. 
    moveToWaitingFromFirewall(order).then(()=>{
                    callback();
                })
How it looks now and no luck

Comment: create a new `moveToWaitingFromFirewall` that is simply a function that returns true or something, you know? Debug the separate parts.

Comment: @CodyG. just realized my other exports function is timing out, possibly a cause? Not sure but ill definitely do what you said and separate them ill come back with results thanks Cody

Comment: @CodyG. I fixed the timeout on the other exports wasnt the issue. But i made a new function that returns true.
`moveToWaitingFromFirewall(order).then(callback);` `function moveToWaitingFromFirewall(order_id){
    return true;
}` and getting error `moveToWaitingFromFirewall(...).then is not a function` Im going to try using .then(()=>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study this a little bit, and maybe apply to your current code.

Imagine `admin.database().ref("orders/"+order_id+"/time_order_placed").once('value')` is like `delay(time)`

```js
// let delay = time => new Promise(res=>setTimeout(res,time));
let delay = function(time){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      resolve();
    },time);
  });
}

let myPromise = function(order){
  return Promise.all([
    delay(500),
    delay(500),
    delay(1000).then(function(){
      console.log('Order complete: ',order);
      return; // returns undefined, so cb doesn't pass anything to cb(err), but use ()=>cb() to avoid this anyways.
    })
  ]);
}

let orders = [1,2,3];

async.each(orders,function(order,cb){
  myPromise(order)
  .then(()=>cb())
  .catch(err=>cb(err));
},function(err,data){
  if(err){
    console.log('Err',err);
  }else{
    console.log('all Finished');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.6.0/async.js"></script>
```

Comment: Im a little confused on the first bit before the actual async.each runs. Since im a newb, the first line is what really confuses me.

Comment: Ha, that first line should kind of be ignored, but it is a very good lesson. I'll write it out in its full form so it is more clear. It's promisfying setTimeout, in a very short manner, so it can be used as if it were a promise simulating an async process that has a delay.

Comment: Also, this all is very confusing because you're dealing with 3 different types of async code (callbacks, async.io library, and promises) and trying to manage between them... I'm starting to realize probably shouldn't be using async.each at all, and could avoid callbacks completely.

Comment: The issue was fixed by adding a callback to moveToWaiting and that callback handles the callback for async function. I am interest though in your thought about making this process way easier. Would be cool

Comment: So get rid of `async.each` by generating an array or promises using `let promiseArray = orders.map(order=> moveToWaitingFromFirewall(order));` then use  `Promise.all(promiseArray).then(...callback)` ... but you shouldn't even have to use callbacks, you should look at converting those callbacks into promises (return promises, and use .then()).

Comment: At First I had it with all promises, the way you described but the code was messy. What you just wrote seems simple, I wonder if that is all thats needed. Going from Java to NodeJS is enlightening.

Comment: Good luck! I think if you struggle through it you'll find yourself very knowledgeable afterwords.   When you get something working but not sure it's the best --- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: thank you Cody! If you know how to mark your statement as answered let me know!

Comment: NP, and oh, click the little checkmark next to my answer. near the up/down 0. You can also upvote it. https://imgur.com/a/P4Nmepq